# Converting from iis 5.1 to iis 7.5

Tags: iis, path

I was running asp pages from xp iis 5.1.  I am trying to run the same pages in win7 iis 7.4.
I'm getting "HTTP Error 503. The service is unavailable" 
I am not getting anything in the logs C:\inetpub\logs\LogFiles\W3SVC1

In IIS Manager Application Pools I started DefaultAppPool.  It is configured to Start Automatically True.  I found in the event viewer for Windows Logs, Application:

```
The worker process for application pool 'DefaultAppPool' encountered an error 
'Cannot read configuration file due to insufficient permissions
' trying to read configuration data from file 
'\\?\C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\CONFIG\machine.config', line 
number '0'.  The data field contains the error code.
```

[image]

What do I need to do to fix the permissions issue?

Thank you,

Docfxit

Comment: Which permissions does the folder in the error message have? Does the IIS user have permission to read it? The IIS user in 7 has changed 'account'/name compared to the old ones

Comment: It looks like it doesn't have the correct permissions. The permissions it has is:  System, ComputerName/CurrentUser, ComputerName/Administrators.  In XP IIS the user permissions needed to be "IUSA_MachineName"(substute MachineName for the actual MachineName).  Is it correct that in IIS 7 it needs to be "IIS_IUSRS"?

Comment: I have a bat file to set the permissions in IIS 5.  Does anyone have a bat file to set the permissions in IIS 7?

Comment: IIS_IUSRS is the equvivalent to IIS_WPG from older IIS, so it should work. The IUSR should be the IUSA_MachineName equvivalent, but I generally just go with IIS_IUSRS myself unless I need something specific in which case I generally opt to use a new domain account to better keep track of the "user".

Comment: I am not getting any events in the event viewer any more.  I'm getting a "The connection has timed out".  Where should I look to find the problem?  Thank you very much.

Comment: It depends on what's throwing the timeout and what it's trying to connect to.

Comment: I have done a lot of troubleshooting.  The results are too large to paste here.  I have posted the results here: http://bin.cakephp.org/view/417276322  I have not found a resolution yet.  Thank you for looking at my findings.  Docfxit

Comment: I found that I need to set Parent paths true.  My current error is: GET /cya/ |423|80004005|Operation_must_use_an_updateable_query. 80 - 75.79.6.149 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.1;+rv:26.0)+Gecko/20100101+Firefox/26.0 500 0 0 131

Comment: From what I have found it's a permissions issue.  I have figured out the default user is IUSR.

This command line will add permissions for IUSR to all files in the web folder:

icacls D:\MyDocuments2\Web /grant %UserName%:(OI)(CI)(M)

Please note: the default folder when IIS is installed is: C:\inetpub\wwwroot

Your's may be different.